# Problem accessing Oracle Database from SQL Server 2016 Database via Linked Servers option

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2016, linked-server

We have recently upgrade-it SQL Server from 2008 to 2016. After that,  we have had an issue accessing an Oracle Database 11gR2 hosted on another machine. We didn't have this problem with 2008 version of SQL Server. After executing a query (OPENQUERY command) with a linked server the following message arises:

> **OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "XXXXXX" returned message "ORA-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable". Msg
>   7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot initialize the data source
>   object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server
>   "XXXXXXX".**

Is this a known bug or we should do an additional configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably has something to do with your OracleHome environment variable. If push comes to shove, you don't have to use TNS to connect - you can take the contents of the TNSNames file and put it directly in your connection string when you're configuring the link.

Comment: Hi dandarc. Thanks for the reply. I have solved this issue. Regards.